# Include ObjectId in a search of Elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoosastic

I am using ElasticSearch and mongoosastic to synchronize data between MongoDB and ElasticSearch.I want to include a property of a schema which is another object in my research: i want to display articles having the category that i'am searching. 
These are my 2 schemas: ArticleSchema and CategorySchema. Article contains a Category object called "Categorie".

```
var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    ...
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    categorie: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        es_indexed:true,
        ref: 'Category',
        required: 'Le champ "Categorie" ne peut pas etre vide'
    }
});

var CategorySchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: 'Please fill Category name',
        trim: true
    },
    ...
    niveau: {
        type: Number
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `ArticleSchema` definition simply needs to properly declare its `categorie` property type (i.e. not `Schema.ObjectId` but `CategorySchema`).

As shown in mongoosastic docs [for nested models](https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic#indexing-nested-models), you can do it like this:

```
var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
    ...
    categorie: {
        type: [CategorySchema],        <--- change the type to this
        es_indexed:true,
        ref: 'Category',
        required: 'Le champ "Categorie" ne peut pas etre vide'
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there another way to reference documents by their ObjectId instead of creating it by the schema as a sub-document? Ie. something like mongoose's ref and populate()?

Comment: Looks like not out of the box. I'll see if I can add that feature through hydration and create a PR for it tonight. Your answer made me look further into the problem and realize the difference between nested models and population. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic/pull/118

```
var Comment = new Schema({
    title: String,
    body: String,
    author: String
});


var User = new Schema({
    name: {type:String, es_indexed:true},
    email: String,
    city: String,
    comments: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment', es_schema: Comment, es_indexed:true, es_select: 'title body'}
})

User.plugin(mongoosastic, {
    populate: [
        {path: 'comments', select: 'title body'}
    ]
})
```

Caveats:

1. You should provide your ref schema to es_schema in order to make a correct mapping
2. By default mongoosastic will index the whole schema. Provide an es_select field on your schema to pick specific fields.
3. The populate array is an array of the same options you pass to mongoose Model.populate